# Deserializing javabeans objects with gson

Tags: android, gson

I'm trying this code, but not working

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { list();}

    private static void list() {

        Gson gson = new Gson();     
        String result = "[{\"Person\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Prédio I\"}},{\"Person\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Prédio II\"}}]";
        Person[] persons = gson.fromJson(result, Person[].class);
        System.out.println("Qtde: " + persons.length);
        for (Person pe : persons) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + pe.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

see that this code takes an array of Persons, but not works, should show me javabens objects

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the problem is with properly binding the JSON structure to a matching Java data structure.  Note that each component in the JSON array is an object that has a single property, named "Person", which is an object with two properties, named "id" and "name" -- each component in the JSON array is not a simple Person object, but a Person wrapper object.

The following demonstrates binding the JSON to a matching Java data structure.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // [{"Person":{"id":"1","name":"Prédio I"}},{"Person":{"id":"2","name":"Prédio II"}}]
    String jsonInput = "[{\"Person\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Prédio I\"}},{\"Person\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Prédio II\"}}]";

    PersonWrapper[] persons = new Gson().fromJson(jsonInput, PersonWrapper[].class);
    System.out.println("Qtde: " + persons.length);
    for (PersonWrapper pw : persons)
    {
      System.out.println("Name: " + pw.Person.name);
    }

    // output:
    // Qtde: 2
    // Name: Prédio I
    // Name: Prédio II
  }
}

class PersonWrapper
{
  Person Person;
}

class Person
{
  int id;
  String name;
}
```